# Why does this regex return a shorter version of the expected?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Can someone help me understand why the following returns `"$123,00"` and not `"$123,000"`?

```
var string = "$123,000 word word";
string.match(/^\$[\d|,]+(?!\s)/g)

// "$123,00" not "$123,000"
```

Would appreciate assistance getting it to return "$123,000"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of your lookahead. When it advances to the last 0, the lookahead matches and the regex fails. So it has to backtrack to the second 0. It looks like you probably want:

```
"$123,000 word word".match(/^\$[\d,]+\b/)[0]
#=> "$123,000"
```

Answer (score 1):

John, why you want to have the negative lookahead assertion if you want the expression to return only "$123,000"? Besides, I think you have misunderstood on the concept of negative lookahead which asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is not space (\s from your question), meaning it will chop the string starting from a character before the space. For more details, you may refer to http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html or you could test and debug your regex in https://regex101.com/ which comes with some explanation on your regular expression.